# Excel Pivot Table converting numbers to text in row labels

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, powerpivot

I have a calculation in a SQL Server View that returns an integer.  Powerpivot retrieves this integer from the SQL view, and it appears to still be an integer (in Powerpivot).  However, the Excel Pivot Table I created from the Powerpivot source is converting the integer to text when I place the value in a row label, resulting in all manner of bad behavior for sorting and charting.

At first I thought perhaps Excel wouldn't allow numbers in row labels, but I've confirmed that it can (just not in my pivot tables).  I've tried applying formatting directly through both Powerpivot and Excel without success.  So I'm at a loss as to why its converting my Powerpivot values, and what I can do to stop it?  Any thoughts and guidance are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would launch the Power Pivot window using the Manage button (from the Power Pivot ribbon).  Then I would select the column of interest and change it's Data Type to Whole Number.